# How to read(import) text from a .doc file using NPOI for .net

Tags: c#, parsing, text, npoi, .doc

I am trying to do something so simple but I can not find a way for doing it.I have viewed the NPOI site few times but they have all kind of problem solvings except mine.I just want to load a .doc(MS Office Word 97-2003) document and get its text and then assign it to a string and use it.It sounds so simple but I just need someone to tell me or reference me to a source where I could get information about that.

Answer (score 3):

Doc is not supported in official release of NPOI. But you can find the source code in ScratchPad folder on github. Try the HWPF namespace